# How to handle error messages when doing jQuery submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I have a partial view which I try to try to do form submit from my client side code. This is working all fine as expected.

But now we have a requirement to handle some error/validation messages which are sent across from the server based on some validations in place (ideally show a alert/toastr message). I am not very clear about what code to add to achieve the same

This is the current code in place:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
   var isFormValid = true;
   //Client side validations sit here 
   if (isFormValid) {
     //How do I handle the error message returned here?
   }else
     e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

TIA

Comment: You cannot handle the server's reply there, because the above code will get unloaded when the form is submitted. You're talking about a "jQuery submit", there's not really such a thing. Do you mean an AJAX submit? As in, sending the form data in the background without leaving the page?

Answer (score -1):

Get a variable whether result is success or fail,
and then use boostrap

```
           if (r.result){
                msg_typ = 'success';
                msg_txt = '<h4>Success!</h4> <p>Issue Note saved</p>';
                $('#form-main').trigger('reset');

            } else{
                msg_typ = 'danger';
                msg_txt = '<h4>Error!</h4> <p>'+r.message+'</p>';
            }

            $.bootstrapGrowl(msg_txt, {
                type: msg_typ,
                delay: 2500,
                allow_dismiss: true
            });
```